# Calculate head of a pipe in MatLab

Tags: matlab

```
function [nodes, pipes] = calculateFlowsAndHeads(nodes, pipes)
% calculate Fi because it doesn't change
pipes(:,6) = 10.67 * (pipes(:,4) ./ ( (pipes(:,5).^1.852) .* pipes(:,3) * 1000^1.852));%making a new column for Fi
pipes(:,7) = zeros(5,1); %flows of each pipe initialised
for pipe_no = 5:-1:1 %start from last pipe
    pipes(pipe_no ,7) = nodes(pipes(pipe_no ,2),4); %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  this on has the ending node but you also need the pipes connected to that node
    if any(pipes(:,1) == pipes(pipe_no ,2))%% check if any pipes are connected to the end node!
       pipes(pipe_no ,7) = pipes(pipe_no ,7) + sum(pipes(pipes(:,1) == pipes(pipe_no ,2),7));
    end
end
for node_no = 2:size(nodes, 1)
    connected_pipes = find(pipes(:, 1) == node_no);
    disp (node_no);
    if ~isempty(connected_pipes)
        % Assuming all connected pipes contribute to the head
        pipes_at_node = pipes(connected_pipes, :);
        nodes(node_no, 3) = nodes(pipes_at_node(1, 2), 4) - sum(pipes_at_node(:, 6) .* (pipes_at_node(:, 7)).^1.852);
    end
end
```

end
i wrote this along with a function to read the data

```
     Six-Nodes Water Network
* node type head(m) draw-off (l/s)
 1 1 30 0
 2 0 0 40
 3 0 0 25
 4 0 0 30
 5 0 0 20
 6 0 0 20
*end
* from to D(m) L(m) C
 1 2 0.30 400 100
 2 3 0.30 600 100
 2 5 0.20 300 100
 3 6 0.25 400 100
 3 4 0.25 750 100
*end
```

as u see there is an error in calculating the head of the nodes

```
Final Pipes:
From Node | To Node | Diameter | Length | Roughness Factor | Flow
    1.0000    2.0000    0.3000  400.0000  100.0000    0.0000  135.0000
    2.0000    3.0000    0.3000  600.0000  100.0000    0.0000   75.0000
    2.0000    5.0000    0.2000  300.0000  100.0000    0.0000   20.0000
    3.0000    6.0000    0.2500  400.0000  100.0000    0.0000   20.0000
    3.0000    4.0000    0.2500  750.0000  100.0000    0.0000   30.0000

Updated Nodes:
Node Number | Type | Head | Draw-off
    1.0000    1.0000   30.0000         0
    2.0000         0   24.9629   40.0000
    3.0000         0   19.9880   25.0000
    4.0000         0         0   30.0000
    5.0000         0         0   20.0000
    6.0000         0         0   20.0000
```

can someone help me with to solve
we know that Hnode = Hnode-1 - Fi*Qi^1.852
i will love if u h help